# npm install did not install the correct version in package.json

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install

I am trying to install `node_modules` for my project, but instead of loading the libraries in `package.json`, npm install the latest ones. Before I used the command npm to `install -g npm@latest`, did it have any effect?
I tried `npm install --force`, `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`, and remove node but it has same error
My package.

```
{
"name": "",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"homepage": ".",
"dependencies": {
  "@ant-design/icons": "^4.0.0",
  "@ant-design/pro-descriptions": "^1.2.0",
  "@ant-design/pro-form": "^1.15.1",
  "@ant-design/pro-layout": "^6.9.4",
  "@ant-design/pro-table": "^2.17.3",
  "@ant-design/pro-utils": "^1.8.0",
  "@react-hook/resize-observer": "^1.2.0",
  "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
  "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
  "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
  "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
  "@types/lodash": "^4.14.168",
  "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
  "@types/react": "^16.9.53",
  "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
  "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7",
  "antd": "^4.11.1",
  "antd-img-crop": "^3.14.1",
  "axios": "^0.21.1",
  "cookies": "^0.8.0",
  "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
  "exceljs": "^4.2.0",
  "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
  "immer": "^8.0.1",
  "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
  "less": "^4.1.0",
  "less-loader": "^7.3.0",
  "loadable": "^1.0.0",
  "react": "^17.0.1",
  "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
  "react-intl": "^5.10.18",
  "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
  "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
  "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
  "read-excel-file": "^5.0.0",
  "redux-injectors": "^1.3.0",
  "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
  "typed-redux-saga": "1.2.0",
  "typescript": "^4.0.3",
  "web-vitals": "^0.2.4",
  "xlsx": "^0.16.9"
}
```

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrGaI.png)

Thanks so much

Comment: please post your `package.json` and the number of the version that is being installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The caret `^` means it can install the most recent compatible version.  If you want it to install a specific version, you can remove the `^` in front of the versions.

See [package.json docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json)
and [semver](https://github.com/npm/node-semver#versions)

The caret will let it install a later version that doesn't change the first number.  For instance your package.json specifies `^4.0.0` for `@ant-design/icons`, but it installed `4.6.2`.  Since the `4` didn't change, that is acceptable.